Can you eat the skins of whole soybeans?
I soaked in hot water and when hydrated I boiled for about 3 hours.
There is a translucent skin around every beans, Do I need to peel that or can I eat it if I don't mind the texture?

Soybean skins are edible, though the texture isn’t the best.  Peeling them is something of a pain, so if you don’t mind the texture then eat them as is. (For tempeh, it’s important to remove many or all of the skins for the structure to develop properly.)

If you microwave edamame (i.e. soybeans), the peels sometimes come off. Not a guarantee but a pleasant sometimes surprise:)
